# Wireshark Windows build fails to: Could NOT find POD (missing: POD2MAN_EXECUTABLE POD2HTML_EXECUTABLE)

Tags: windows, perl, wireshark

I'm trying to build Wireshark 3.2.5 on Windows 10 for the first time according to official guide at: https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChSetupWin32.html

So far I'm at chapter *2.2.12. Generate the build files* after installing the depencies and Strawberry Perl. The build is failing to
`Could NOT find POD (missing: POD2MAN_EXECUTABLE POD2HTML_EXECUTABLE)`

The guide doesn't say anything about those. How to install pod2man and pod2html on Windows?

Comment: I have Strawberry Perl version 5.30.1 on Windows 10. When I installed Strawberry Perl it also installed `pod2man`. It is a batch file located in `C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\pod2man.bat`. What does running `where perl` from CMD prompt give you?

Comment: Thanks! Added `where perl` output path `C:/Strawberry/perl/bin` into file `cmake/modules/FindPOD.cmake` and now the build progresses.